# Linking with BLAS OS X

Tags: c++, c, compilation, linker, blas

I am currently trying to compile a program using a library that I'm not very familiar with. When I run the compiler, I get the following output/error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_cblas_ddot", referenced from:
      shark::LDA::train(shark::LinearClassifier<shark::blas::vector<double> >&, shark::LabeledData<shark::blas::vector<double>, unsigned int> const&) in libshark.a(LDA.cpp.o)
      shark::LDA::train(shark::LinearClassifier<shark::blas::vector<double> >&, shark::WeightedLabeledData<shark::blas::vector<double>, unsigned int> const&) in libshark.a(LDA.cpp.o)
```

My current idea is that this is from missing BLAS library, which I just downloaded and compiled (from fortran code?).

The command-line arg for compiling looks like thsi

```
g++ -o example -I/to/boost/include -I/to/shark/include -L/to/boost/lib -L/to/shark/lib -L/to/BLAS -lshark -lblas -l(boost_flags)
```

In `/to/BLAS`  have a `libblas.a`, and I ran `nm  libblas.a` which gives a line

```
libblas.a(ddot.o):
00000000000001c0 s EH_frame1
0000000000000000 T _ddot_
```

Without being too secure abut this, I assume that this means that the library does have the symbol, but without the `_cblas_` prefix.

What can I do from this point? Can I change the symbols name? Or do I need to link this library with something else?

I use OS X Mavericks

Thanks in advance : )

Comment: Do you have access to the source file LDA.cpp? On the face of it, it appears that you might need to add something into your link, if you can get  clue what to add. Examining LDA.cpp might provide such a clue.

Comment: I'm not even sure if I have LDA, I'll look into that, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OS X ships with BLAS (including cblas) already installed (it's part of the Accelerate.framework).  There's no need to download and build your own.  Just link with `-lcblas`.

Comment: Ah damn! I tried -lblas without luck. This might have saved me some time.

Comment: -lblas will actually work too.  The problem is that the linker was finding your /to/BLAS/libblas.a (which doesn't have the cblas interfaces) rather than the system blas library (which does).

Answer (score 1):

Solution was as suggested by Logicrat, that I needed other files, I downloaded te source code from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GfortranBuild) and build it with cmake/make very seamless. Linking with the libraries that came from this resolved the issue.